# Another flippin Comma Question!

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This sentence is from the dictionary:

"Congenial means sharing the same temperament, or agreeing with your temperament."

How's the comma functioning in the aforementioned sentence? What rule is being implemented?

It obviously feels natural to have the comma placed there, but does it fit into any of the prescribed rules for commas? I can tell you that it separates the coordinate completers of the finite verb of the sentence, but why? The phrase after the comma is a noun phrase--which can only lead me to assume it's behaving as an appositive (but with a conjuction attached). Correct thinking?

Thanks in advance for responses.

Comment: You make 'the Dictionary' sound like 'the Bible' ;-)  There are many dictionaries and some are more reliable than others. In fact this is from vocabulary.com http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/congenial. Please don't keep your sources secret.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK The source is irrelevant as the question isn't about the meaning of the word *congenial* but about placing a comma between two elements of a dual compound construct.

Comment: No comma is needed there.

Comment: @Drew Could you explain why?

Comment: @deadrat: Nope.

Comment: @Drew That's fine:  it was a prompt, not a quiz.  It just means you haven't answered the question.

Comment: @deadrat: I didn't provide it as an answer (though it is one).

Comment: Apologies for not specifying the source, @ChaslyfromUK. Didn't think which '[D]ictionary' it came from was important... So nobody has an explanation for its use?

Comment: @Deadrat, by sheer coincidence, your first comment presents a similar scenario to the initial question asked. I always see writers put a comma between 'congenial' and 'but' in your comment with sentences of a similar form, yet I cannot fathom why!?

Comment: @Sean Check my answer, which was posted after your comment.  Tell me whether it makes things clearer or cloudier.

Comment: @Drew Not a helpful one, but as always, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punctuation is a matter of style, and these styles are documented in various guides, which all have the same purpose: to set marking rules to help the reader convert linear script into the tree-like syntax intended by the author.  One generally unwritten rule is to break any written rule when the result helps the parsing.  First we have to guess that the comma was placed with an eye to following or breaking some rule and wasn't just a typo.  If we decide it's not a typo, then we have to guess which rule of which guide the writer intended to follow or ignore.  That said:

I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which prescribes that a comma separate two compound independent clauses, but not two compound phrases.  Here the phrases are

> 1. sharing the same temperament
> 2. agreeing with your temperament

two noun phrases that form the compound direct object of *means*.

But when the reader hits *or* there's another possible parse, namely the **compound object of the gerund *sharing***.  For example:

> Congenial means sharing the same **temperament or disposition**....

Here the two compound elements are nouns

> 1. temperament
> 2. disposition

Obviously, the reader who makes this mental choice will have to re-parse once he hits *agreeeing*, and I think the comma is there to prevent a reader from making the temporary and erroneous choice.

Steven Pinker in his book *Sense of Style* calls these choices "garden paths" because they lead readers down dead-end paths, requiring them to back up and re-parse.

Answer (score 0):

That was an excellent description. I can think of one guideline that a comma would be placed: representing opposing viewpoints within the same sentence. Such as "I was pleased, not mad." I also use CHICAGO, which is nice because it allows for personal style and flow. In your sentence above, I would either use an em-dash in place of the comma, or perhaps I'd use italics for the word "your" and leave out the comma.